# Gillespie's Algorithm's Connection to Kolmogorov's Forward Equations

Tags: simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I've been learning Gillespie's algorithm to simulate continuous time Markov chains. I understand how the algorithm is derived from the reaction probability density function

$P(\tau, \mu)$ = probability at time $t$ that the event $\mu$ will occur in the time interval  $(t + \tau, t + \tau + d\tau)$

What I don't get is how this guarantees us that we're sampling from the "master equation" or the Kolmogorov forward equations. Why is that sampling with this probability gives us trajectories that follow the distribution given by solving the forward equations?

Comment: The short answer is that the reaction PDF is directly obtained starting from the Kolmogorov equation. I think this gives enough guarantees. The probability inside Kolmogorov equation gives the probability that the system is in a certain state at a certain time, which is different to what the reaction PDF describes, but both refer to the same system.